# Formula to compare two columns and say billed or not billed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I am looking for a formula that would to compare the two columns in Excel, find if there is a match or not, and place the number that matched in a new column, and if it didn't match, instead of putting the number there, I need it to signify there was no match, or N/A

Can someone please assist?

[image]

[image]

The two screenshots below show the columns that I need to compare.  They are headed differently but they are the same.

These are on two different sheets, I can move them on the same sheet if need be.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you need a match per row, or if there's a match at all? (Meaning, `A1=B1` or search for `A1` in the entire `B` column?)

Comment: How do you want to treat multiple matches (even if you don't expect them)? A formula could certainly show the first matching result using `INDEX/MATCH`. But I don't think it is possible if more than one match is found (and you might care to list all matches with a `,` delimiter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MATCH:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!G:G,MATCH(G2,Sheet2!G:G,0)),"N/A")
```

Comment: I believe this worked great, but I am not returning the entire matching number, I am only getting 3 or 4 digits for some reason.  Can you assist?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're two columns that you're comparing are columns A and B and you want you're result in column C this will do it: `=IF(AND(A1=B1,B1<>0),B1,IF(B1<>A1,"N/A",""))`... then just drag down

Comment: Please see my edit, would this apply for what I am trying to do?

Comment: @AlexImperiale They're on separate sheets, so no. Where do you want you're out put to go ("No match" / "N/A")?